# 'The 'Pods' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries' when installing 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'

Tags: ios, cocoapods, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios, swifty-json

I am trying to install 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils' but it gives me above error.
Here is Podfile :

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
 use_frameworks! 
 target 'MapClusters' do
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
end
```

I tried to remove `pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'` and it did work. So I guess Google-Maps-iOS-Utils is the one causing problem. Here is the full error :

```
[!] The 'Pods-MapClusters' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/Users/BAPS/Documents/Test/MapClusters/Pods/GoogleMaps/Subspecs/Base/Frameworks/GoogleMapsBase.framework, /Users/BAPS/Documents/Test/MapClusters/Pods/GoogleMaps/Subspecs/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMapsCore.framework, and /Users/BAPS/Documents/Test/MapClusters/Pods/GoogleMaps/Subspecs/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework)
```

I have already gone through lot of answers here or elsewhere on web. 
Till now I have tried these solution :

1. Disabling the check for transitive dependencies.

   2.`pre_install do |installer|
      def installer.verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies; end
   end`

   `post_install do |installer|
   find Pods -regex 'Pods/GoogleMaps.*\\.h' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' 's/\\(<\\)GoogleMaps\\/\\(.*\\)\\(>\\)/\\"\\2\\"/'`
   `find Pods -regex 'Pods/Google-Maps-iOS-Utils.*\\.h' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' 's/\\(<\\)Google-Maps-iOS-Utils\\/\\(.*\\)\\(>\\)/\\"\\2\\"/'
   end`

After adding above two points in Podfile, installation works but then when I try to run the app I get this error:

[image: Error]

After removing `pod 'SwiftyJSON'` it works but I need it there.

I tried few other things too but nothing seems helping. I am new to ios development so I am not able to help myself.

I am using swift, xcode 7.3 and latest cocoapods.

Comment: Check in your framework by expanding whether `GoogleMaps.h` file is there or not. Add framework properly with all header files.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara I am not able to figure it out. Where exactly I have to look. And if it's not present then how can I add it there?

Comment: I am little busy, give me some time i will look into it tomorrow for sure.

Comment: Open your framework directory expand it you will find a `header` directory inside it, all the header files for that framework resides there, if its missing download it from [github](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils) or use [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/?q=google%20maps%20ios%20util)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had figured out this after much struggle. On request google guys have put a tutorial on their git repository.
[Here is the link](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/Swift.md)

Comment: the link is dead. do you know where it's now?

Comment: Here's a copy on the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20191119115600/https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/Swift.md

Answer (score 1):

Used this code in podfile to avoid error while pod install:

```
pre_install do |installer|
    def installer.verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies; end
end
```

But still need solution for pod lib.

Answer (score 0):

please update your pod file

```
    platform :ios, '9.0'
 use_frameworks! 
 target 'MapClusters' do
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils', :git => 'https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils'
end
```